# Проблема в несоответствии расстояний в верстке и фотошопе

Tags: css, вёрстка, photoshop

При верстке макета я меряю отступы в пикселях.

[image: Фотошоп]

В стилях записываю эти отступы, а выходит совсем не то, что нужно.

[image: Верстка]

Почему отступы в макете так не соответствуют отступам в верстке, и что с этим делать?

Comment: Нужно учитывать и высоту строки `line-height` + `font-size` и проверяйте верстку с помощью pixel perfect расширения!
Если изображение, например, логотип - смотрите с какими размерами Вы его сохраняете, бывает что остается пустое пространство, которое и дает еще отступ.

Comment: Дело в том, что так происходит не только с лого. Но если я буду измерять в процентах и стили запишу так же, то выходит правильно. Но не всегда в процентах можно записать отступы)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего проблема в адаптивности страницы (поведении при изменении разрешения). Скорее всего проблема именно в разрешении.
Либо у логотипа есть отступы слева. Чтобы их посмотреть открой режим отладки в браузере. В хроме это ctrl+shift+I, либо пкм > просмотреть код. В остальных не знаю.

Comment: А что можно сделать в том случае, если проблема в разрешении? Кстати, если отступы измерять в процентах, то выходит нормально. Но так не всегда получается записывать.

Comment: Что мешает подобрать расстояние экспериментальным путём?

Comment: Каждый элемент подбирать?) Не очень удобно)

Comment: Посмотри разрешение фотки и настрой отступ. Или в процентах) Кстати в каких например случаях тебе что то мешает задать отступ в процентах?

Comment: Что, если использовать zoom в стилях чтобы уравнивать разрешение в браузере и фотошопе?) В процентах не получается отступы задавать, например, если нужно разместить элемент внутри другого блока, так как в фотошопе расстояние в процентах всегда измеряется относительно размеров всего макета, а в стилях по-разному.

Comment: Нет. Такое не прокатит. Зум может увеличить или уменьшить размер только в заданное кол-во раз. Вряд ли поможет. Кстати можешь дать ссылку на планкер?